# MySQLi Result for a [table][name] not work

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I'm updating the PHP version of a website and I'm having a problem.

I have the query

```
$sql = "SELECT user.name, job.name 
        FROM job 
        INNER JOIN user 
        ON user.jobid = job.id 
        WHERE user.id = 1";
```

But when I use the function: `mysqli_result($query, 0, 'user.name')`
it brings no result.

I know a solution is to name the fields with different names, but as it is a system already done for version 5.3 of PHP and I am upgrading to version 7.0, there are several query's already defined and I do not want to change them.

I got this function:

```
function mysqli_result ($res, $row = 0, $col = 0) {
     $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
     if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row> = 0) {
         mysqli_data_seek($res, $row);
         $resrow = (is_numeric($col))? mysqli_fetch_row($res): mysqli_fetch_array($res);
         if (isset($resrow[$col])) {
             return $resrow[$col];
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

since `mysqli_result` is not native.

Comment: Instead of "user.name" just use "name" because that's the actual column name.

Comment: Why don't you adjust SQL to `$sql = "SELECT user.name as \`user.name\`, job.name as \`job.name\` FROM job INNER JOIN user ON user.jobid = job.id WHERE user.id = 1";` to be able to keep the column name in original form, containing the dot?

Comment: and if the query is like this: "SELECT * FROM job INNER JOIN user ON user.jobid = job.id WHERE user.id = 1" to use mysqli_result ($ query, 0, 'user.name')?

Comment: What is `$query`? You shouldn't have the space between the `$` and name.

Comment: I used the google translate and we added spaces in the code. @user3783243 $query is $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);